# Oracle database client on OS X?

Tags: macos

I am looking for a way to run the Oracle database client on a Mac running OS X. The server will be on a remote host.

There used to be a Mac version of Oracle 10gR2 Client, but now I can't find it on Oracle's site, they only have the newer 11g Client which has not been ported to OS X.

Not interested in virtualizing another OS.

Comment: Have you tried using the Instant Client: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html ? How are you connecting to the database?

Comment: No, I was under the impression that Instant client was something completely different. I don't connect to the database at all right now, this is more of a hypothetical question.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the Instant client is just a slightly cut down version of the normal client. But you really haven't stated what your requirements are. More information here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html

Comment: Thank you, James! I'm sorry I haven't been sharing my intentions, but suffice it to say, the instant client worked like a charm. I grabbed the Basic package, as well as the SDK and SQLPlus for good measure, and simply copied dylibs to /usr/lib, .h files to /usr/inlcude and sqlplus itself to /usr/bin, per these instructions -  http://stackoverflow.com/a/684359/1474902.

Answer (score 1):

Never tried it, just found this: [MacSequel](http://www.macsequel.com/)

> MacSequel is Oracle Query tool written from the ground up for your Mac OSX. I made this because I was sick of all those bloated "Java" based tools which takes minutes to load and consumes huge amount of memory. MacSequel is native Mac, starts quickly, runs smooth and is not bloated with thousands of features you will never use.
>
> [image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: So edit it rather than voting to delete it!

Comment: It should be your duty to edit the posts to prevent them from becoming deleted, not others'.

Comment: @cagcowboy Site still exists, but the download now 404s.